# How do I count all the image tags within an HTML string?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a string of HTML produced by a WYSIWYG editor. I am using Angular for my project.

Let's say I have some stringified HTML like this:

```
'<p>Here is some text with an image</p><br><img src="data:base64;{ a base64 string }"/>'
```

How can I parse this string on the browser-side and count all the `<img>` elements?

Do I need to use regex or is there an NPM package that I can use on the browser-side that will do this for me?

Note: I don't want to render this HTML in the browser. I just want to count the image tags for validation purposes.

Answer (score 3):

With DOMParser, you can create a document from the string and use `querySelectorAll` to select and count them:

```js
const str = '<p>Here is some text with an image</p><br><img src="data:base64;{ a base64 string }"/>';
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const imgs = doc.querySelectorAll('img');
console.log(imgs.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the fastest and simplest way is to consider that any html element `<img>` must always start with `<img`. You can then just search the number of occurrences. This also supports malformed html such as `<iMg`

```js
var msg = `<p>Here is some text with an image</p><br>
           <img src="data:base64;{ a base64 string }"/>
           <iMg src="" />`

const n = msg.match(/<img/gim).length

console.log(n) // 2
```

Comment: Try using a regex to make it more resistant to malformed HTML. Also, nice solution - I tried to use `match`, but that had an error if there were no matches. This solves it in one go.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon thank you, I edited your suggestion accordingly for any number of white spaces between `<` and `img`

Comment: White spaces won't render an image (try it out if you want), but rather changing the capitalization (such as `<ImG`) can be present and still render an image.

Answer (score 0):

CertainPerformance's answer works, however, you can also use javascript's built-in `match` function (because it looks like you are looking for a regex-type solution):

```js
var str = '<p>Here is some text with an image</p><br><img src="data:base64;{ a base64 string }"/>';
numMatches = str.match(/<img/igm);
if (numMatches != null) {
  numMatches = numMatches.length;
} else {
  numMatches = 0;
}
//The string "<img" is needed because a text can have the string "img", but angle brackets are specially reserved for HTML tags. Also, this prevents the matching of </img>, in case there is a closing tag (though there typically isn't)
console.log(numMatches);
```

Comment: This is a quick solution, but prone to error.

Comment: How so? I don't see anywhere it can go wrong. Do you? If so, please let me know so I can update the regex expression. Also, note that you can't put a space between the angle bracket and the "img" tag name, because if you did then it wouldn't render an image.

Comment: Your answer is case sensitive, doesn't work with broken or malformed html, and throws an error if there are no matches.

Comment: Fixed it! Any other issues?